# What are the risks of using an outdated Ubuntu version?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, lubuntu, 10.04, hardware

Can anyone tell my of risks using an older version of Ubuntu (10.04) might have? I'm a simple user who uses a PC for web-surfing, Libreoffice and entertainment (watching movies, music, etc.).

P.S.: I'm already aware of lightweight distros and other desktops, but what I'm looking for is an older kernel which can support my old (unsupported) hardware.

P.S. II: While back in Windows, I was using XP and 7 with no antivirus for the same purposes. Is using older versions of Ubuntu riskier than that?

UPDATE: By risk I mean security risks like bugs, known issues or maybe become a victim of hackers and personal information get stolen! Things like these.

Comment: What is the old hardware you need to support?

Comment: Can you edit the question and specify what kind of risks you would like to protect against? Malware? Bugs in critical system components? Outdated software?

Comment: @raffaem its the VGA. NVIDIA 7200GS/7300SE (NVIDIA 304.135).

Comment: @merdad You will be left with Firefox 3.x, and it may not render modern websites correctly (someone else may be able to better explain what are the risks of using an old browser. I don't know about the exact risks). 

If you don't have plans to connect to the internet, and want to use it as a media center, that's perfectly fine.
It would still be much safer than using XP or 7 with no antivirus. But the browser may be an issue. You may find an appimage of a later version of firefox that may work with Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @raffaem I just did that, thnks

Comment: If you're offline, the risks are non-existent (though if you are using files transferred via usb-thumb-drive etc. they are no longer nill, but are still small). I wouldn't browse the web from such a machine, and likely restrict it to a unique VLAN on the local network, as it's possibly (you provided no details) some programs if they use network data, may cause increased risk to other machines to your network (the machine will be easier prey for attack, esp. targeted).

Answer (score 4):

If you're offline, the risks are non-existent (though if you are using files transferred via usb-thumb-drive etc. they are no longer nill, but are still small).

I wouldn't browse the web from such a machine, and likely restrict it to a unique VLAN on the local network, as it's possible (you provided no details) some programs if they use network data, may cause increased risk to other machines on your network (the machine will be easier prey for attack, esp. targeted attacks).

You weren't specific to what use you intend for the machine, I've already mentioned I'd restrict it to it's own VLAN and not let other machines on my local network speak to it. I'd also look up what programs I was to use, and look for flaws that were detected in that software, but were never patched for your **EOL** system.  These checks (or *homework*) are time-consuming, and are part of why updating to supported software is easier & safer.

Many **privacy** attacks on browsers are specific to a browser, eg. if it targets chrome (or `firefox`), it'll impact users regardless of OS (so windows, mac & GNU/Linux users almost equally).  In these cases; using an older browser would increase the security risk *in my opinion*, unless using a atypical browser such as `lynx` that doesn't run any scripts usually used for such attacks (*thus having a smaller attack risk*).

You mention 10.04, which reached EOL on [2015-April-30 for servers](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-April/000196.html), and [2013-May-9 for desktops](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2013-March/000169.html) (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2015/04/30/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-end-of-life-reached-on-april-30-2015/ https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so that's a lot of potential security risks that you are un-patched for, and a lot of *homework* to ensure your system is safe.

If you were talking about say [Lubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://lubuntu.me/xenial-released/), where the desktop itself has been EOL since 2019-April, but the Ubuntu *base* still gets security patches, my concern would be *lower*, also the amount of *homework* I'd need to do to assess the risks is far less and I may consider it (*I'd still treat the box with concern & be careful what I did on it; but I'm somewhat careful anyway, having multiple boxes I do things specific things on*).

(*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS can have extended security when it reaches EOL in 2019-April through the use of [ESM](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm) which can involve paid subscriptions but is also available free of $cost. It doesn't include all packages, but is still of far lower security risk than say 10.04 LTS*)

The risks will vary on your use-case, packages installed, protocols those packages use (*using network traffi*c) plus what system you installed and what was detected since security maintenance ceased. Yes this can be assessed (the *homework*), but as time is often more expensive than hardware, is it worth it?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is still available (see link used in answer), if you need older software, however I used machines as old as 2003 using pentium 4, pentium M & like processors in testing Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, Xubuntu 18.04 LTS etc & later (whilst i386 ISOs were available meaning into the disco/19.04 cycle).. so I see no need for using an older release as I can't imagine anyone using pentium III or other older boxes...

Comment: If you're using a pentium II/III processor, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS maybe the *newest* that you can run, as I do recall loads of issues on boxes that old with new machines; but anything that old will just cost you $s in power bills for almost no real processing power anyway (ie. very power & cost ineffective!).  Hardware that old is usually only used as later boxes weren't ISA, and you had a specific card/hardware-device that worked there but was pre-USB era etc.. but those boxes usually aren't used online.

Answer (score 1):

Security-wise, if all you do is web-surfing, Libreoffice and entertainment, and not running a server or anything, and you use it at home and not connected to public network all the time, there is very low risk of being hacked even without the security updates. Ubuntu systems are hardly ever targeted anyway. Just be smart when surfing the web. More importantly are the linux drivers, some of which might be proprietary. You might be missing some drivers for the latest hardware or peripherals but it shouldn't matter to you if you're just browsing the web all day. Even if you need them, you can just manually install them without upgrading the entire ubuntu version. Long story short, if you have constraints and do not want to upgrade ubuntu there are no significant risks.

Comment: Many **privacy** attacks on browsers are specific to a browser, eg. if it targets chrome (or firefox), it'll impact users regardless of OS (so windows, mac & GNU/Linux users equally).  In these cases; using an older browser would increase the security risk in my opinion, unless using a atypical browser such as `lynx` that doesn't run any scripts usually used for such attacks.

Answer (score 0):

as others have mentioned, we'll need to be rather generic in our responses without more information. But let's consider it to be a random desktop tower with a common intel CPU, a generic NVIDIA 304 driver as you had mentioned, and Ubuntu 16.10 or older.

I'm not going to bother inferring your use case, instead a more direct approach is to provide tools that can be used under any scenario- [vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)) and [exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)) lists! Every operating system will inevitably have software that will one day reveal a security vulnerability and perhaps someone will create an exploit for that vulnerability to truly take advantage of it, however the rate of these compromises is measured loosely by a number of websites through reporting. One such website, aptly named cvedetails.com https://www.cvedetails.com/index.php has been reliable for me in the past as a systems administrator.

Not all software is likely to have vulnerabilities or exploits, for example, the likelihood of a basic text editor or music player having the ability to let someone remotely access your system and gain increased privileges (access to root) or prevent you from using the computer (denial of service).

But let's put that last thought to the test, are the vulnerabilities for [xed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xed) or [Rhythmbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox)? According to CVE details, there are for Rhythmbox, but only in 2009 and 2012 as far as we know! Xed, on the other hand, doesn't even show up! So what about something like Ubuntu? Well, fortunately you don't need to search for every single available software under Ubuntu, you only need to look at two things:

1. Ubuntu ([Products and Vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/51/Ubuntu.html) OR; Ubuntu Version, e.g. [Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-4781/product_id-20550/version_id-194088/Canonical-Ubuntu-Linux-16.04.html))
2. [Debian](https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/23/Debian.html)! Because it's the *base/root* and it maintains much of the software that Ubuntu uses.

Looking upstream is always important, even if your upstream is ahead or behind the downstream in version. For example, Debian is often behind Ubuntu in updates because that's simply how the project is run for stability- and yet because they're still the primary maintainers, you can clearly see that they have way more operating system specific vulnerabilities.

Something to note, the Ubuntu vulnerabilities and exploits page does not include anything from custom PPA's except for the built in system used to install PPAs.

Moving away from focussing on the user software, your old intel processor may have a number of vulnerabilities associated with it too. For example, [Spectre](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-5754/) has affected a number of operating systems and all the specified references for Spectre can be found in the link to cvedetails- but in future you can always use a search engine like Google to search "site:cvedetails product exploitname" if you don't know the specified CVE number. Newer operating systems, or operating systems that have received security updates, will have patched something like Spectre, so if you're out of security updates and you think that you may later be at risk of running exploit code for that vulnerability, then perhaps you should update.

If anyone has any questions, please let me know, happy to help!